# Spring Integration implementation of ESB?

Tags: java, spring-integration, esb

Is Spring Integration(SI) implementation of ESB . I am aware that SI is implementation of EIP but how  SI related
to ESB?

Comment: Is Mule ESB specific implementation of ESB ?